# Generic over both the lifetime and the value category

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

### Motivation

I am trying to write a dynamically-typed function wrapper:

```
type Action = Box<dyn Fn(&mut Ctx)>;

struct Ctx(Vec<Box<dyn Any>>);

impl Ctx {
    fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> &T {
        todo!()
    }

    fn take<T: Any>(&mut self) -> T {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

`type Action` is a dynamic function which accepts a context and takes data from it or borrows depending on the underlying closure.

To build an `Action` I am using the additional trait `Contextual` which *knows* how to pull itself from the context:

```
trait Contextual {
    fn pull(ctx: &mut Ctx) -> Self;
}
```

Here is `trait ActionBuilder` which leverages `Contextual` to build `Action`:

```
trait ActionBuilder<Args> {
    fn to_action(self) -> Action;
}

// May be more/fewer than two arguments
impl<A1, A2, F> ActionBuilder<(A1, A2)> for F
where
    A1: Contextual,
    A2: Contextual,
    F: Fn(A1, A2) + 'static,
{
    fn to_action(self) -> Action {
        Box::new(move |ctx| self(A1::pull(ctx), A2::pull(ctx)))
    }
}
```

It's relatively easy to `impl Contextual for <Some Value>`, but it's quite hard to do for the reference type. Please see the test below I am using:

```
fn test() {
    impl Contextual for String {
        fn pull(ctx: &mut Ctx) -> Self {
            ctx.take()
        }
    }
    let _x = (|_: String, _: String| ()).to_action();

    impl Contextual for &Vec<i32> {
        fn pull(ctx: &mut Ctx) -> Self {
            ctx.borrow() // doesn't compile: lifetime may not live long enough
        }
    }
    let _x = (|_: &Vec<i32>, _: String| ()).to_action();
}
```

I've tried to bring a lifetime parameter to `Contextual<'a>`, but still cannot accomplish this. In short, it wants me to put the lifetime of the context at the top, but I cannot have it on the top, since at the place of creating an instance of `Action` I may not have a context at all.

### Simplified version

I've ended up with the following simplified code which shows the issue. Please see below.

```
trait Contextual<'a> {
    fn pull(ctx: &'a mut Ctx) -> Self;
}

impl<'a> Contextual<'a> for String {
    fn pull(ctx: &'a mut Ctx) -> Self {
        ctx.take()
    }
}

impl<'a> Contextual<'a> for &'a Vec<i32> {
    fn pull(ctx: &'a mut Ctx) -> Self {
        ctx.borrow()
    }
}
```

Function `good_lib_fn` is generic over the lifetime and compiles well:

```
fn good_lib_fn<'a, A, F>(ctx: &'a mut Ctx, f: F)
where
    A: Contextual<'a>,
    F: Fn(A),
{
    f(A::pull(ctx))
}

fn good_user_fn(mut ctx: Ctx) {
    good_lib_fn(&mut ctx, |_: String| {});
    good_lib_fn(&mut ctx, |_: &Vec<i32>| {});
}
```

The function `bad_lib_fn` cannot be generic over the lifetime, because it accepts all the arguments by value. And the code below doesn't compile.

```
fn bad_lib_fn<A, F>(mut ctx: Ctx, f: F)
where
    A: for<'a> Contextual<'a>,
    F: Fn(A),
{
    f(A::pull(&mut ctx))
}

fn bad_user_fn(ctx1: Ctx, ctx2: Ctx) {
    bad_lib_fn(ctx1, |_: String| {});
    bad_lib_fn(ctx2, |_: &Vec<i32>| {}); // doesn't compile: implementation of is not general enough
}
```

So, `good_lib_fn` works well, because it uses fixed lifetime `'a` and can infer all the trait implementations.

I think `bad_lib_fn` should also use some fixed lifetime which would be equal to the body of the function `bad_lib_fn`, but I am not sure if it's possible to encode this:

```
fn bad_lib_fn<A, F>(mut ctx: Ctx, f: F)
where
    A: Contextual<'bad_lib_fn_body>, // something special here
    F: Fn(A),
{
    f(A::pull(&mut ctx))
}
```

### Update

Found an issue trying to implement `Contextual` for pair.

```
impl<'ctx, A1, A2> Contextual<'ctx> for (A1, A2)
where
    A1: Contextual<'ctx>,
    A2: Contextual<'ctx>,
{
    fn pull(ctx: &'ctx mut Ctx) -> Self {
        let a1 = A1::pull(ctx);
        let a2 = A2::pull(ctx); // cannot borrow `*ctx` as mutable more than once
        (a1, a2)
    }
}
```

That means that despite the issue described earlier, the whole approach should be reworked. Introducing interior mutability could help though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be done.

Even just explaining *why* runs into nasty details of the language and its type system (quick keywords: late-bound and early-bound lifetimes, specialization), but unless all of your parameters are always references or always owned, this can't be done.

The best you can do is implementing `ActionBuilder` manually.

Comment: > implementing ActionBuilder manually

Do you mean without `Contextual` at all?

Comment: 3rd option was to stick with the lifetime-less version but add [unsafe] lifetime casting along with marking `unsafe trait Contextual`, but I wanted to avoid that... However that may seem like a solution actually, of course, if done right.

Comment: @DmytroStarosud You can still have `Contextual` for easiness but `pull()` the values manually. And of course you can go with unsafe code, but you will have to be very careful and I don't recommend this path.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean... Could you expand your suggestion a bit? Maybe you could add some code to your answer.

Comment: @DmytroStarosud By "manual `pull()`"? [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=202724c14e0dd1e66732c05f2f8a0e04). Of course, it is up to you to decide whether this is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! That works well already (I've amended a bit your gist), but will require a macro though. Will try to play a bit with that approach...